# Is there a pure CSS workaround for multiple browser prefixes?

Tags: css, vendor-prefix

The more and more we venture into the wonderful world of CSS3, the more and more we all get annoyed by the fact that these features require a MASSIVE amount of browser prefixes to allow compatibility with some older browsers. This problem becomes quite apparent even for small sites, where we need 4 or 5 CSS properties for the exact same effect. A common example would be the background property for gradients.

I know that there are scripts that can help with this issue, but before resorting to those, is there a pure CSS fix that would allow you to work around the prefix issue, or at the very least, some sort of method to keep the extra amount of typing to a minimum? That is, combining things, shorthand, whatever. CSS files can easily double with CSS3-rich content.

Comment: And how can CSS fix the CSS browser compatibility issue?

Comment: The issue is with the prefixes, not compatibility, even though they are quite similar. While I'm aware we need the prefixes for older versions, the problem is that we have to write much more, which is what I'm wondering about. How much can we compact and combine in the CSS? Can anything be written shorthand to keep file size and lines to a minimum?

Comment: I assume that prefixes are a kind of compatibility issue. Anyway, the answer is no, there's no **pure** CSS way to overcome CSS prefixes issue.

Comment: It's not a pure CSS workaround, but it solves your problem: see https://github.com/LeaVerou/prefixfree

Answer (score 0):

I totally agree to the excessive code need to accomplish the same effects in CSS3 but that issue is on the browsers side as other comments stated.

One design practice/tool/technique i think best to follow is using LESS when writing css. 
I see the The possibility of over coming this issue (for now) with it. Checkout it out here. http://alittlecode.com/handling-multiple-css3-transitions-with-a-less-mixin/.

If you are not sure what is LESS then check this out - http://www.lesscss.org/.

Yes it is pure CSS from my perspective, but no as stated before, it won't reduce the size of files.

Comment: `i think best to follow is using LESS` I'd say using CSS preprocessors.